# GPIB driver for linux (kernel 3.x)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I was wondering if there are any gpib drivers available for a modern kernel (>3.x). All the comercial drivers and the only non comercial driver I found, linux-gpib,  support only up to 2.6.
I'm using linux mint 13 by the way. I tried to install linux-gpib, but I actually have no clue how to do that correctly.

Thanks in advance.